# Late response from API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, ionic-framework

I am learning TypeScript and currently I am trying to use google API for books. Issue that I have, is that at the time when expect to get get a response I have null. However, I am logging response and data is presented console. Next strange this that, this data is logged and the end of all my code (like the last thing, but not when I am actually doing logging method).
Is there a way to wait for response? My code parts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { OrderPage } from '../order/order';
import { BooksApiProvider } from '../../providers/books-api/books-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-book',
  templateUrl: 'book.html'
})
export class BookPage {

    books:any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public booksProvide: BooksApiProvider) {
    }

  moveToOrder() {
    debugger;
    this.books = this.booksProvide.getBook();
  }
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class BooksApiProvider {

  constructor() {
  }

  getBook(){
    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9780439139601')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getBook()` method doesn't return anything, therefore, `this.books` will always be null.
As you're using `fetch` here, you can return the promise in your `getBook()` method allowing you to perform any action with the data retrieved.

```
getBook(): Promise<any> {
  return fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9780439139601')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      return Promise.resolve(data);
    });
}
```

Then you can call `.then` on `getBook()` to do whatever you want with the data.
(Assign the data to `this.books` for example)

```
this.booksProvide.getBook()
  .then(data => this.books = data);
```

You're using Angular thought, you should take a look at the `HttpClient`. It's pretty much the same as `fetch` unless it deals with RxJS and `Observables` which are widely used in Angular.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. It worked, I need to read more about this Promise thing. Thanks again !!!